# Narrow convergence and support of the limit measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a Polish metric space and $\{\mu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of probability measures such that $\mu_n\rightarrow\mu$ narrowly (i.e. $\int_Xf\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\rightarrow\int_Xf\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ for any $f$ continuous and bounded). If there exists a compact set $K$ that contains the supports of the $\mu_n$'s then does it contain also the support of the narrow limit $\mu$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Portmanteau Theorem?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures

Comment: not so much, does one of its statements involve the definition of tightness/narrow convergence to prove the statement?

Comment: If $\mu_{n} \to \mu$ narrowly, then, for each compact $K$, $\mu(K) \geq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu_{n}(K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(X,d)$ is a Polish space, any finite Borel measure on $X$ is tight ([Ulam's theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Tight_measure)). Hence, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
1=\mu_n\big(\text{supp}(\mu_n)\big)\leq\mu_n(K)$$

The Portmanteau theorem implies that
$$\mu(K)\geq \limsup_n\mu_n(K)=1$$
Therefore $\mu(K)=1$, and the from the definition of support, $\text{supp}(\mu)\subset K$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried like that:

Assume that $K\supset\bigcup_n\mathrm{supp}\,\mu_n$ and let $x\in\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$. I want to prove that $K\supset\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$.
So let $x\in\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$. By definition of support of a measure there exists an open nhood $\mathcal{N}_x$ of $x$ such that $\mu(\mathcal{N}_x)>0$. Using the Portmanteau's theorem$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu_n(\mathcal{N}_x)\geq\mu(\mathcal{N}_x)>0.$$So $\exists\bar{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq\bar{n}$ we have $\mu_n(\mathcal{N}_x)>0$. But now $x\in\mathrm{supp}\,\mu_n\subset K$ and we're done.

Remark: compactness was needed for a bigger theorem I needed to prove, and a "minimal" $K$ need to be closed. As counterexample, pick $\mu_n=\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ over the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidian topology. We have that 1) $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and 2) that $\delta_{x_n}\rightharpoonup\delta_{x_0}\Leftrightarrow x_n\rightarrow x_0$. In this case if we take $K=\bigcup_n\mathrm{supp}\,\mu_n=(0,1]$ we wouldn't have $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu\subset K$ being $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu=\{0\}$ so here a "minimal" $K$ should be closed.

Comment: oh you're right, thank you!

Comment: IT may be necessary to assume that the support of the $\mu_n$'s exists in the sense that $\mu_n(\operatorname{supp}(\mu_n))=1$. I am not sure that being a proper metric space  (bounded closed balls are compact) implies that, unless some additional separability assumptions are made.

Comment: In the paper I'm reading $X$ is a Polish space (complete and separable).

Comment: I assumed that $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu\neq\emptyset$ so at least it must contain a least point. Then I chose $\mathcal{N}_x$ precisely beacuse I can choose any open nhood of it

Comment: @MatteoCalisti: as OliverDiaz indicated, your proof is not correct for you are using the definition of support of a measure correctly.

Comment: ok I'll try to think, beacause I thought that starting from the support there would't be problems since it must hold for every nhood of $x$. In any case, can you provide me with a reference about the Ulam's theorem? (never heard about it)

Comment: P.s. in any case, i know that proper implies completeness for metric spaces. But if the space isn't separable why the assumption $\mu_n(\mathrm{supp}\,\mu_n)=1$ may fail?